# Push a page outside Ion Tabs

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

How can I push a Page outside of ion-tabs? I'd like to show a detail page where the tabs are not shown.

The case is: I have my Tabs App where I have a list on the first tab and I want to click an item and navigate to the details page of that item and not to show the tabs, only the details and a back button.

Comment: The details page is a lazy page btw.

Comment: Please take a look at the **[Ionic's Config docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/config/Config/)**: `tabsHideOnSubPages (boolean): Whether to hide the tabs on child pages or not. If true it will not show the tabs on child pages.`

Comment: Thank you @sebaferreras. Problem solved :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :)